# call a function when the program is finished with ctrl c

Tags: linux, function

I am working in the Linux environment, and I have a C++ program, what I want is when I cancel the program with ctrl+c I would like that the program executes a function, to close some files and print some sutff, is there any way to do this?. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`signal()` can be dangerous on some OSes and is deprecated on Linux in favor of `sigaction()`. ["signal versus sigaction"](https://www.petesh.com/archives/2008/11/signal_versus_sigaction/)

Here's an example that I ran across recently (["Tap the interrupt signal"](http://cc.byexamples.com/20070520/tap-the-interrupt-signal/)) and modified as I was playing around with it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<string.h>

struct sigaction old_action;

void sigint_handler(int sig_no)
{
    printf("CTRL-C pressed\n");
    sigaction(SIGINT, &old_action, NULL);
    kill(0, SIGINT);
}

int main()
{

    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
    action.sa_handler = &sigint_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, &old_action);

    pause();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The actions in sigint_handler() after the printf() are odd - why?  Also, you should pause() instead of your while loop.  The initialization for the new action is not ideal, either.  It probably works, but is a bit of scattershot "let's hope that all zeroes is OK" approach.

Comment: I have updated it to use pause() instead of the while loop as that really does make more sense even for demonstration code.

As I said in the post, the code originally came from elsewhere. I may have misread it but I thought it would save off and restore any existing signal handlers.

Comment: This is a nice working example, but I think that struct sigaction action, old_action; should be struct sigaction action; That is, it seems you redefined the name of your global old_action in main().

Comment: Notice that `sigaction` is not part of ISO 9899 (C standard), whereas `signal` is. For portability, it might be useful to use `signal` instead, especially when the implementation differences are uncritical (e.g. a signal handler that terminates the program).

Answer (score 8):

For a full working example you can try the following code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

volatile bool STOP = false;
void sigint_handler(int sig);

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
    while(true) {
        if (STOP) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void sigint_handler(int sig) {
    printf("\nCTRL-C detected\n");
    STOP = true;
}
```

Example run:

```
[user@host]$ ./a.out 
^C
CTRL-C detected
```

Comment: STOP should be declared volatile -- otherwise, the compiler might make some (incorrect) optimizations.

Comment: I'm no C++ expert so I'll take your word for it and update the code sample :-)

Comment: Technically, it should also be a sig_atomic_t too.  POSIX allows you to do more in a signal handler than ISO C does.  Also, you should use sigaction().  All else apart, if the user uses a program to generate two interrupts quickly, your program may die using signal() instead of sigaction().

Answer (score 4):

You have to catch the SIGINT. Something like this:

```
void sigint_handler(int sig)
{
    [do some cleanup]
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
}
```

[loads more detail here](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html)

Comment: Much better to use sigaction().

Comment: Jonathan - please expand on that assertion.

Comment: answer above expands on it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368927/call-a-function-when-the-program-is-finished-with-ctrl-c/376059#376059)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: look into the signal function, specifically catching SIGINT. You write a callback function and pass it to the system via the signal function, then when that particular signal happens, the system calls your callback function. You can close files and do whatever other cleanup stuff you want in there.

Comment: Much better to use sigaction().

Answer (score 0):

Note to people who might stumble upon this question, looking for the answer in **Windows** instead:

Use the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` API call to set a custom handler and watch for `CTRL_C_EVENT`, `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` or `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`.