# Execute a last function in C when I make Ctrl+C in terminal

Tags: c, linux, terminal

1. I have a C program running (in terminal)
2. My program has a loop(`while(1){}`, for example),
3. So if I want to stop it, I have to press `ctrl + C`

**My question:**

Is there any way to run a last function in my C program when I press Ctrl+C?

For example I typed `Ctrl+C` in my linux terminal an then my program detects that I typed `Ctrl+C` and it prints something like "bye bye" or open a file, etc.

Hope, you understood me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you read about [signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). The signal in this case is `SIGINT`.

Comment: use sigaction(SIGINT, &action, &old_action) to set and define your exit function in callback sigint_handler() see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368927/call-a-function-when-the-program-is-finished-with-ctrl-c

Comment: You might also get by with an [`atexit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `signal` call to install a handler for the SIGINT signal.

Answer (score 1):

when you press ctrl+c a signal SIGINT is generated. so you need to write a function to catch that signal. for that you can write a function say,

```
void catch_signal_ctrlC(int s)
{
//...
  printf("Bye");
}
```

then to catch signal register as,

```
signal(SIGINT, catch_signal_ctrlC)
```

this system call will register catch_signal_ctrlC() function to catch SIGINT i.e. it will be called whenever you press ctrl+c in terminal

Comment: Notice that what you are allowed to do (safely) within a signal handler is quite limited.

Comment: ... and `printf()` does **not** belong the those. Also `signal()` could be look as being depreciated. Use `sigaction()` instead.